# To run a new ODB-II line from car computer

Tags: engine, obd-ii

I bought a used Toyota Camry 2010 sometime in August. I noticed that there is no OBD-II port in the car. I have checked everywhere in the driver side and even passenger side.
I noticed the car was involved in an accident later which might be the reason a lot of work was done on it which might have led to the removal of the OBD-II port.

Question: It there a way to replace the OBD-II in the car? That is by running a new connection to wherever it connects to in the car. 
Thanks.

Comment: try : https://www.hum.com/port/

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks but I've seen this site before and I know exactly where it's supposed to be. It's removed.

Comment: Are you sure? Has it just been tucked up and away ? It could easily be quite a distance up behind the dash wrapped around some wiring somewhere... and fiendishly difficult to spot.

Comment: @SolarMike - You're most likely right ... however, finding it may be like the proverbial needle-in-a-haystack situation. Whether running wiring for a new port, or finding the old one, would need to find the wires from the PCM/ECU. This would allow tracing wires back to where the port is at or running the new wires. However, finding a wiring diagram online for this is proving problematic. The only ones I can find are the paid ones. Great fun.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes. I found it. I took it to a mechanic who disassemble underneath the dash and found the port buried inside. It has been placed on the spot now. Thanks for your help. I don't think I can delete the question at this point. Finding my OBD-II port doesn't address the question but I'm happy I did.

Answer (score 1):

The first image below indicates the OBD2 connector is just below the fuse box behind the knee panel left of the steering column. The one marked DLC3. If it is not there look to see if it got moved somewhere else close or look for a cut wire harness.

Image 2 is the wiring for the DLC3 connector (E10), and the 3rd is the pinout for the DLC3 connector (E10)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you see the last comment b y the OP? port found and sorted...

Comment: Missed it but hopefully my answer will help others here, thanks.